# MongoSharding - Request Distribution

Tags: mongodb, node.js, asynchronous, mongo-shell

Regarding : Request Distribution issue and System Getting troubled.

Recently I configured MongoDBSharding in production server and details given below.

1. I taken 3 individual machine for mongo sharding configuration purpose.

   - First Machine - (shard1 primary + shard2 secondary + shard2 arbitor) + Config
   - Second Machine - (shard2 primary + shard1 secondary + shard1 arbitor) + Config
   - Third machine - Config
2. I am having more than NODE.JS server. So i started mongos with chunk size 5 MB in each NODE Server (for example taken 6 NODE server and 6 mongos instant in each NODE server).
3. After I configured the sharding setup in mongos, created one database and that has been taken in "shard2" as primary automatically.

But my problem was I cant able to distribute the request to the both sharding which I am getting from NODE.JS, because its automatically taken shard2 as primary for that database. So all request hit into the shard2 instant only. So second machine getting troubled for load issue and getting more CPU usage.

Please share your input and suggestion for fixing this kind of issues.

## Diagram

CLIENT -> NODE.JS SERVER -> MONGODB [FIRST MACHINE + SECOND MACHINE + THIRD MACHINE ]

Comment: Is there any way you could revise your question to more clearly describe the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's enough data yet? Even with the low chunk size of 5MB (keep in mind that this only 1/13th of what 10gen recommends, I'd stick to the default unless you're perfectly sure you need this value), you'd have to have at least 50MB of data in that collection until sharding starts AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a [shard key](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key)?

Comment: I specified an shard key in each collection of that database. But each collection doesnt have an records and empty collection. Because its a new features we have implement, so based on user transaction it will be filled in that collection in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. All data goes to the primary for the database by default until it starts splitting the data. Once it's split it'll be directed to the correct shard rather than going to the primary, but the split operation must have already happened. You can also presplit. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Splitting+Shard+Chunks